# EclipseでのPHP構築：実行やデバッグの操作方法、事前必要設定を把握したい

Tags: php, eclipse

先日Eclipseを入手したばかりで一応にPHP Development Toolsのセットアップも終えている認識です。
http://proengineer.internous.co.jp/content/columnfeature/5404
を参考に、自分が作成したphpのコーディングをPHP CLIアプリケーションという実行方法で無事動作させることもできました。
Eclipseの下部コンソールに現れたのはHTMLでした。

===質問===
①このHTMLソースを別途エディタに貼り付けて、ブラウザで確認しない限り、実際ブラウザで表示されるイメージは認識できない、ということでしょうか？
ブラウザイメージで確認できる方法があれば、（Webサーバとの関連付けなど事前に必要とのことであればそれも含め）ご教示をお願い致します。Eclipseから出来ればの話です。

②デバッグという操作があるようですが、VBAみたいに行単位のステップ実行などができればと思っています。試しに虫マークのアイコンを押してデバッグ操作を試行したところ"There is no PHP server specified in 'test(1)' launch configuration."というエラーを招きます。
この点についても事前に必要な設定などがあればご教示をお願いいたします。

Comment: CLI向けにPHPでスクリプトを組みたいのですか？それともWEBページとしてPHPを処理したいのですか？WEBページとしてならXAMPPを立ててらっしゃるようですしXAMPPの公開ディレクトリにおいて`http://localhost/`で確認されてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: webアプリケーションのデバッグ(動作確認)をしたいのであれば、webサーバも必要になります。その辺りを過去の質問でXAMPPの設定だったりをしてたと思うのですが、そちらの環境はどうなってしまったのでしょうか。

Comment: いつもお世話になっております、またご見解をありがとうございました。
WebサーバにPHPのコードをディプロイする前に一体どこまでEclipseで検証が行えるのか・どこまでの範囲を行うのが
常識のなのか分からなくてお問合せさせて頂きました。
勿論自分の端末にはXAMPPでApacheの設定も済んでいます。
過去に自分がVisualStudioでASP.NETのサイトを作っていた際はデバッグモードの動作で
かなり仕上げられていた印象でしたから、Eclipseも同じ意識を働かせてしまいました。
ブラウザのイメージで動作結果を確認する場合はもうEclipse上で行うべきでない、ということですかね？
（VisualStudioではデバッグモードの動作を行うとASP.NET開発サーバという開発環境内Webサーバが自動で立ち上がり
IISへディプロイする前に同等の動作確認ができていた認識）

Comment: Eclipse単体ではブラウザイメージの動作検証を行えず、当該端末にセットアップされたWebサーバとの連携でブラウザイメージの検証・デバッグがなされる、という認識は正しいでしょうか？
（事前にApacheをあげておく必要があるなど）

Eclipseから実行・デバッグできるのは、プロジェクト内のものに限定という認識ですが、これも正しいですよね？？

従来まではエディタでサイトの構成要素・phpファイルを作成してきていた為、動作確認の際はこれらをApacheのDocumentRoot=htdocsに配置した上、ブラウザの起動=localhost/サイト名/XXXXX.phpで行ってきました。
上記の確認を踏まえると、それらをEclipseのプロジェクト上で管理しない限りはElipse経由の実行・デバッグができない、と認識です。これはは正しいですか？

当該開発端末のEclipseからの実行でブラウザイメージの結果を捉えたい場合、ApacheのDocumentRootを、Eclipseのワークスペースに一致させるのが常識ということでしょうか？
（ApacheのDocumentRootがC:\xampp\htdocsと定義されていたら
EclipseのワークスペースもC:\xampp\htdocsと定義するのが常識？）