# EclipseでPHPのデバッグ操作を達成するためxdebugが利用できるよう設定したい

Tags: php, eclipse

EclipseでPHPのデバッグ操作ができる、という情報を入手しました。

http://keicode.com/cgi/introducing-xdebug.php
の記事を参考に設定を試みていますがphpinfo()へ「xdebug」の文字が現われず、のっけから躓いております。

php.iniの最後に、入手したdllの配置箇所を以下要領で追記、Apacheの再起動後にphpinfo()の確認を行っています。
zend_extension_ts = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.7.0alpha1-7.0-vc14-nts.dll"

試行している開発端末はx86・PHPは7.0.28です。
正直申し上げてhttps://xdebug.org/download.phpから取得したdllが、自身の環境に見合っているのか定かではありません。

やはりphpinfo()にxdebugが現われないのは　適合外のdllを入手している、ということでしょうか？
何が問題なのでしょうか？
皆様ご見解をお待ち申し上げております。

===デバッグを開始すると以下エラーがブラウザに表示されます===
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

===Eclipseの画面を見た限りXdebugが起動てきるようになった、ということ？===
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: https://xdebug.org/wizard.php こちらのxdebugのwizardは実行しましたか？

Comment: keitaro_soさん　いつもお世話になっております。
ご提示のウィザードは試していません。
ご紹介のページに大きなテキストボックスが現れていますが、こちらに
自分のPHPINFO()の内容をマルマル貼り付ける、もしくは
コマンドプロンプト上でphp -iで得た結果を貼り付けるということでしょうか？

Comment: そのとおりです。この方法は公式のドキュメントにも載っています。https://xdebug.org/docs/install やはり一番信用できるソースは公式のドキュメントなのでこちらを参考にしてください。

Comment: keitaro_so様　お時間を頂き誠にありがとうござます。試しに紹介をうけたページのテキストボックスへ自分のPHPINFO()の内容を貼り付けて、下段にあったコマンドボタンを押してみたら、
なんと適合のdllが示され、php.iniファイルの編集方法まで具体的に示されました。本当に助かりました。
無事自分のPHPINFO()へxdebugが表示されるようになりました。重ねて御礼を申し上げます。

Comment: 解決したのであれば、どのようにして何をしてXdebugの起動まで進んだか自己回答をしておいてください。

Comment: phpinfo()にxdebugが表示されるようにはなったのですが、Eclipseのデバッグを押すとブラウザでエラーが表示されます。
本文に貼り付けましたが、[an error occurred while processing this directive] 要求された URL は本サーバでは見つかりませんでした。 もし手入力で URL を入力した場合は、綴りを確認して再度お試し下さい。 [an error occurred while processing this directive] 
というエラーです。Eclipseのデバッグ構成の場面で、対象ファイルの選択=プロジェクトに唯一存在するphpファイルを指定した程度なので
またEclipse上で設定が漏れているのかも知れません。
もはやデバッグとは関係ない問題でしょうか？別のスレッドを立てるべきでしょうか．．．

Comment: ひょっとしてEclipseからxdebugを動作させる行為は、当該端末のWebサーバ：Apacheに
開発成果物を配置してサイトのURLへアクセスしている動作確認と同意ですか？？？
Eclipseを入手したばかりで、Webサーバとの関係を全然認識していなかったのですが．．．。

ワークスペースとやら、Eclipseの初回立ち上げ時のデフォルトのまま作成してしまったのですが
本来はApacheのhtdocsを指定するのが常識なのでしょうか？？？
それともEclipse側から実行・デバッグするとしても、ワークスペースはソース環境という位置づけで
いちいち事前にhtdocsに開発成果物を移行してから、Eclipseから実行・デバッグするのでしょうか？

Comment: @saya24 「xdebugを利用できるようにしたい」がこの質問の主題なはずで、keitaro_so さんのコメントを元に「phpinfoに表示されるようになった」のであれば、質問は解決済みとして一旦クローズすべきです(自己回答で記録を残しましょう)。その後に続けている内容は、恐らくxdebug以前にEclipseのデバッグ設定に関わる内容で、あなたが作成した[1つ前の質問、「Eclipseでのデバッグの操作方法や設定を把握したい」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/44186/3060)で取り扱うべき内容です(まだ回答は付いていないようですが)。

Comment: @cubick　ご見解ありがとう御座います、今しがた対応致しました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

皆様いつも大変お世話になっております。
keitaro_soさんの手ほどきで、自分の開発端末にPHPのデバッグユーティリティをセットアップすることができました。phpinfo()へxdebugの文字が表示されない、というのが当初の問合せでしたので、これ自体は達成されたので本スレッドを解決と致します。

-解決までの道のり-
①https://xdebug.org/download.php
へアクセスしてxdebugのdll入手を試みるも、沢山ありすぎて自分のphpにどのverが相応しいのか正直分からない状態だった。一応x86版の7系を入手して、php/extに格納、その後php.iniのその有効化（パス）を記述、Webサーバも再起動

②phpinfo()にxdebugが表示されない

③こちらに記事掲載して、keitaro_soさんからhttps://xdebug.org/wizard.phpの紹介を受ける。
大きなテキストボックスが配置されいるページで、自身の開発端末のphpinfo()まるまるを貼り付けて、分析用コマンドボタンを押下せよ、との内容と解釈。

④半信半疑ながら上記実施。コマンドボタンを押下。すると自分のphp 7.0.28に適合するxdebugのdll（ver）が、リンク表示された。これを押下するとダウンロードすることができ、extフォルダへの配置、iniファイルへの記述方法、Webサーバの再起動が必要とまで記載されており、まさにこれどおり従うと、見事自分のphpinfo()へxdebugの文字が現れるようになった。

ご報告まで